# Why the operator forkJoin does not work?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm trying to add two observable. But the console does not display anything.

```
var s = Rx.Observable.of(100, 200, 300);
var s1 = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);

var sub = Rx.Observable.forkJoin(s, s1)

sub.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

[live example here](https://jsfiddle.net/zlodiak/g5pj065m/9567/)

For the case of two synchronous observables there is no problem

Comment: `forkJoin`: [When all observables complete, emit the last emitted value from each.](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html); `interval`: [Emit numbers in sequence based on provided timeframe.](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/interval.html) (doesn’t complete).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`forkJoin` emits only when all its source Observables emit at least one item and all of them complete. Using `Observable.of` is fine. It emits all its values and completes immediately. But `Observable.interval` never completes on itself (you might want to chain it with `take(N)` for example.

```
var s1 = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(1);
// Now both source Observables complete so `forkJoin` will complete as well
var sub = Rx.Observable.forkJoin(s, s1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look up the [forkJoin() function](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-forkJoin) in the official documentation you will see:

> forkJoin will wait for all passed Observables to complete and then it will emit an array with last values from corresponding Observables.

If you look at the [interval() function](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-interval)

> interval returns an Observable that emits an infinite sequence of ascending integers ....

So your forkJoin works fine, it will just never `console.log()` anything, because the interval function doesn't end.